# how to use javascript object properties in onjects functions

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use the property "list" as seen in my code within the for loop for the function createList but unless i define lists like  var list = .....; within the createList it does not work.

```
    var app = 
{
    list:document.bluetoothList.pairedDevices,

    createList : function()
    {   

        for(var i=0; i<5; i++)
        {
            app.list.options[i] = new Option("name" + i, "mac" + i);
        }

        document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=app.list.options[app.list.selectedIndex].value;

    },

            prints : function()
            {

                document.getElementById("address").innerHTML=app.list.options[app.list.selectedIndex].value;
            }

}
```

Comment: can you post the object contained in `document.bluetoothList.pairedDevices`

Comment: You probably can't do this.

Comment: document.bluetoothList.pairedDevices
comes from
    ......
 <form name="bluetoothList">
  <select name="pairedDevices" onchange="app.prints();">
  </select>
 </form>

 
 <div id="address">
  
 </div>



 </body>
   <script>
    app.createList();
    </script>
    </html>

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `app.list.options`, try `this.list.options`.

If that doesn't work, I don't know what will - I've used it like that in my code and it worked, so it should for yours, too.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access list properties outside of the app object then you should use `app.list`
but if you want to access within app object then you should use `this.list` and also if `create()` function is a callback function then `app.list` is the perfect one.